# Security tag using iBeacon

Tags: ios, monitoring, ibeacon

I would like to implement an application that will perform continuous ranging on a single beacon and alert when the estimated distance is more that a choosen value.
How can this be achieved in iOS in background mode and receive an alert when the distance is greater than a value and not when the device is out of the beacon region? Is there any way?

Comment: Look at the documentation for CLLocationManager, specifically the didRangeBeacons:inRegion: method. This is a very broad topic and Stackoverflow is here to help solve issues with what you have tried and worked on, so try to get it working and if you can't, then please post the code and your problem and we may be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

iOS limits the amount of time you can range for beacons in the background to save battery.  By default, ranging stops within 10 seconds of when your app goes to the background, but this can be extended to 180 seconds with special tricks.  You can read more about this here:  http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/11/13/extending-background-ranging-on-ios.html

The above restriction aside, what you suggest is possible.  You have to decide for your use case if a foreground-only operation app, or one that is limited to working for 3 minutes in the background is viable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  I cannot figure out how make it works. I Would like the beacon to be  put on a pet or a child an receive an alert when they are going away, but it can be too late if I have to wait for the exit region event. In android is quite easy to have continous ranging in background, How can a similar behavoiur be achieved in iOS?